# How to send an Enum variant as integer, not string in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 11, and have to post some data to a backend service. Here's the data I need to post:

```js
interface User {
    id: Guid; // Guid is just a type alias to string, with some validation checks
    email: string;
    role: Role
}

enum Role {
    User = 0,
    Administrator = 1
}
```

Now the problem comes when I try to post to my backend using the default HttpClient from Angular. Here's the code:

```js
createOrUpdateUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.baseUrl}/${this.userUrl}/${this.userCreateOrUpdate}`, user);
}
```

This works fine, but the JSON sent is "wrong". It sends this:

```json
{
    "id": "2abe50d6-4c81-4ace-ad95-c8182d4384a3",
    "email": "someEmail@example.org",
    "role": "0"
}
```

Where as the backend is expecting this

```json
{
    "id": "2abe50d6-4c81-4ace-ad95-c8182d4384a3",
    "email": "someEmail@example.org",
    "role": 0
}
```

The difference being the backend expects `"role": 0`, but Angular sends `"role": "0"`. How can I make Angular send `"role": 0`?

Comment: you can use + to make it as number before sending it api  user.role = +user.role

Comment: Ok, that worked out. I'm still kinda confused as to why though. If you want, you can post this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is may not be a good idea. But it will be helped you.

```
createOrUpdateUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    user.role = Number(user.role);
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.baseUrl}/${this.userUrl}/${this.userCreateOrUpdate}`, user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use + to make it as number before sending it api user.role = +user.role. Some where else you are assigning value of role in user object which is making it as a string. its not enum issue.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is compiled to plain old javascript code, where type enforcement is more or less non-existent. This means that, in theory, you might be assigning a string to your `User` model.

There can be multiple reason - i.e. you receive it this way from backend, assign it to a variable and re-send later without modifying the value. Or, for example, the User comes from a FormGroup which passes the value as a string. You can even have TypeScript code omit type checks:

```
let user: User = {
    id: '2abe50d6-4c81-4ace-ad95-c8182d4384a3',
    email: 'someEmail@example.org',
    role: Role.Administrator
}

user['role'] = "2" // Not a valid enumeration
```

So, to instead of going for some strange workaround like using +user.role in the mapping, perhaps look for where / how the value is assigned in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As it is not really clear if it gets sent from angular or received from server as string we can debug a bit to find the right place to investigate (angular frontend or backend)

You can investigate by logging `console.log(typeof user.role)`and see what it returns. Also have a look at what gets sent from frontend to backend using Chrome Devtools -> Network -> click on the request -> and scroll down on first tab to see what data gets sent.

What might happen is frontend to send the right data type (integer) for the role and backend interpret it as string.

In this case you could just use `parseInt(user.role)` in the backend as a fallback or investigate how to get the integer type on the backend body request instead of string.

Comment: I think it's quite clear that Angular sends `"role": "0"`, but the server expects `"role": 0`. I can verify this using Postman. Angular is "wrong" here in sending `"0"` instead of `0`